# JQuery Ajax Success not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure why my ajax success isn't being triggered/called.
My controller is called and the code is executed fine. I'm not returning anything, so my method is a void! Do I need to return something (ActionResult/JSonResult/etc) to get the success to trigger?

Here is my controller code.

```
public void DeleteEvent(string eventId)
{
    diaryEventService.DeleteDiaryEvent(eventId);
}
```

Here is my ajax call.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/ManageSpaces/DeleteEvent',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    eventId: eventId,
  },
  success: function() {
    //var obj = JSON.parse(doc);

    var myCalendar = $('#fullcalendar');
    myCalendar.fullCalendar();
    myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventId);
    $("#eventDetails").collapse('toggle');
  }
});
```

Comment: You should implement error and check what is happening there,

Comment: It should return `JsonResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to return `JsonResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteEvent(string eventId)
{
    diaryEventService.DeleteDiaryEvent(eventId);
    return Json("{status:"OK"}");
}
```

Since you are changing back-end data, set it to POST:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/ManageSpaces/DeleteEvent',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
     eventId: eventId,
    },
    success: function(response) {
    if(response.status=="OK"){
     var myCalendar = $('#fullcalendar');
     myCalendar.fullCalendar();
     myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventId);
     $("#eventDetails").collapse('toggle');
    }else{
      console.log("Error occured")
    }
   }
 });
```

Comment: If they're deleting something, then DELETE would be a better Http Verb.

Comment: Right krillgar. but delete, put methods would send OPTIONS request along with the actual request. So POST is also fine.